# Python Generator: confusing result

Tags: python, generator, yield

I'm playing around with generators to better understand how they work, but I'm confused with the result of the following piece of code:

```
>>> def gen():
...  for i in range(5):
...   yield i
...
>>> count=gen()
>>> for i in count:
...  print count.next()
...
1
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
StopIteration
>>>
```

What's going on here? Looks like as it hits the "for i in count:" line the generator yields the first value. I'm not sure.

EDIT: I should add that I'm not trying to "get it right". I'm trying to break things to see how Python reacts. I learn more about the language when I generate errors. This error had me stump but it's all clear now.
So far all the answers have been short and sweet. Thank you every one!

Comment: `for i in count` and `count.next()` are *both* trying to get the next item - why are you using them both in the same loop?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should be like this

**Code:**

```
def gen():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i

count=gen()
for i in count:
    print i
```

**output:**

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

**Notes:**

When you loop `for i in count` you trying to get the next item again here `count.next()` you trying to get the second element .So basically you are trying to get element +2 from current position

So what happens in you code is  are as below:

**steps :**

1.`for i in count` here the next value is got which is`0`

2.`print count.next()` here again next value is called and printed so `1` is printed

3.`for i in count` here again next value is called which is `2`

4.`print count.next()` here again next value is called and printed so `3` is printed

5.`for i in count` here again next value is called which is `4`

6.finally here you are calling `print count.next()` since there is no value in the generator .You have been give the exception `StopIteration`

Answer (score 3):

Because "for" cycle already iterate your generator values, at every step two values are yielded: one in "for" and one in body of cycle.

Comment: I really like how you captured all in one sentence. I was trying to formulate a short answer but I was unable.

Answer (score 2):

`for i in count:` is already calling next (and assigns the value to `i`). Your code is then calling next again.

If you just want to print each value

```
for i in count:
    print i
```

or the long way round

```
while True:
    try:
        print count.next()
    except StopIteration, si:
        break
```

Comment: Your "long way around" is interesting. I'll practice this too.